# Passing json encoded MultiDimensional Array to javascript via onclick event

Tags: javascript, php, json, multidimensional-array

Passing a multidimensional array to javascript via onClick event and sub-arrays are being read only as `object`.

This is the `json_encode`d array:

```
{
    "products": {
        "41::": {
            "key": "41::",
            "product_id": "41",
            "name": "iMac",
            "model": "Product 14",
            "shipping": "1",
            "image": "data/demo/imac_1.jpg",
            "option": [],
            "download": [],
            "quantity": 3,
            "minimum": "1",
            "subtract": "1",
            "stock": true,
            "price": 100,
            "total": 300,
            "reward": 0,
            "points": 0,
            "tax_class_id": "9",
            "weight": 15,
            "weight_class_id": "1",
            "length": "0.00000000",
            "width": "0.00000000",
            "height": "0.00000000",
            "length_class_id": "1"
        }
    },
    "token": "17263a44810f21b88362f908d2c4be02",
    "customer_id": "1"
}
```

Which returns perfectly when `json_decode`d in php, but in javascript via console.log(data):

```
{products: Object, token: "17263a44810f21b88362f908d2c4be02", customer_id: "1"}
```

The php:

```
`<a id="button-checkout" class="button" onclick='checkOut(<?php echo $json; ?>)'>
        <span>Process Cart to Order</span></a>`
```

The javascript:

```
function checkOut(data) {
    console.log(data);
    return false;
}
```

Am I missing a step?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's exactly expected. You are logging the data object, which contains three properties. The first property is named `products` and it's type is `Object`, the second is named `token` and it's type is `string` which is outputted, and the last is `customer_id` whose value is `1`. If you were to call:

`console.log(data.products)`

you would get a log of the properties of the `products` object. You could do this for each of the properties of each of the objects to log their values. You can think of JavaScript objects as a hash of key value pairs, where the value could be anything including another hash of key value pairs.

Answer (score 2):

The issue is that PHP Arrays != JavaScript Arrays.

In PHP, arrays can have indices that are non-numeric (aka a hash table or associative array). In JavaScript, the *only* arrays there are are those with numeric indices.  Everything else is an object.  The JSON you have above represents an object in javascript.

Check your console log again. I know in chrome you can expand the object keys, and I bet you will find that all of your data is there.

Comment: That's not entirely true. Array's are actually just JavaScript Objects with some extended functionality. Which means that everything in JavaScript, *including* Arrays, are Objects. Likewise, a JavaScript object is simply a collection of properties. In other words, JavaScript objects are essentially a hash of key value pairs (a hash table/associative array like construct).

Comment: You are correct. I thought about including that in the answer, but I didn't want to include too many nuances that weren't technically necessary in answering the question.  Thanks for pointing that out, though.

Comment: thank you both. i "gave" the "answer" to pje 'cause the points will make a bigger difference. Now I need to figure out why `$.parseJSON(data);` is returning null.